# Ubuntu - Error while installing any software/package

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, dpkg

I am newbie in ubuntu. (Version 9.10) I get following error while installing any software from the Ubuntu Software Center.I also get same error while I update ubuntu from Ubuntu Update Center.

Any help??

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the database is damaged. You could try [to restore it from a previous state](http://phantom.byu.edu/pipermail/uug-list/2009-October/002923.html), like this:

```
sudo sh -c 'zcat /var/backups/dpkg.status.1.gz > /var/lib/dpkg/status'
```

Make sure to copy the file first to another backup.

**Edit:**

```
su
zcat /var/backups/dpkg.status.1.gz > /var/lib/dpkg/status
exit
```

Comment: Thanks.I tried that but it doesn't respond after I hit enter after the command.Cursor keeps blinking.

Comment: @ravi: Oh sorry...I should stop c/p commands...pleas try the the edit version.

Comment: Thanks again.But after trying the edited version it gives error as
"su: Authentication failure"

Comment: means that you need to `su` or `sudo -s` to the superuser account before you can do the next step.  If you use `su`, you type the root password.  If you use `sudo`, you type your password.